# creating dynamic query in variable

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am creating a dynamic query in sql server 2005 stored procedure and I am getting error if 
dates are sent empty/null to the stored procedure that:

```
This input parameter cannot be converted
```

So, how to check in Stored procedure that covert only id date is not empty:
below is my query. I have checked the null in if condition but then also it is showing me error

```
If @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @endDate is Not null
    Begin    
       set @strCondition = ' FO.Rf_Date  >= convert(datetime, ''' + Convert(varchar,@startDate,112) + ''') and  FO.Rf_Date<= convert(datetime, ''' + Convert(varchar,@endDate,112) + ''')'
    End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can be empty *or* null you need to also exclude the empty variables, E.g.

```
IF NULLIF(@startDate, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(@endDate, '') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of ISDATE() Function along with CASE statement something like this..

```
SET @strCondition = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 1 '     --<-- 1 = 1 so you can append any more line starting with 'AND'
                   + CASE WHEN ISDATE(NULLIF(@startDate,'')) = 1  
                           THEN   N' AND FO.Rf_Date  >= convert(datetime, ''' + Convert(varchar,@startDate,112) + ''') '
                          ELSE N'' END
                   + CASE WHEN ISDATE(NULLIF(@endDate,'')) = 1                        
                           THEN  N' AND  FO.Rf_Date  <= convert(datetime, ''' + Convert(varchar,@endDate,112) + ''')'
                          ELSE N'' END
```

**Note**

ISDATE() function returns 0 if the passed parameter isnt date value, It also returns 0 is the passed value is NULL.